# Display values in edit

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to display my edit values in the editContact page. I ran out of ideas as to how I'm supposed to fix this.

Here's my controller for edit

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult editContact(int? id)
{
    var databaseModel = new database();

    if (id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    IEnumerable<contact> contact = databaseModel.displayContact(id);

    return View(contact);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult editContact(contact editModel, int id)
{
    try
    {
        programEntities db = new programEntities();
        var databaseModel = new database();

        if (databaseModel.editContact(editModel, id))
        {
            ViewBag.AlertMsg = "Contact edited successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View(ex);
    }
}
```

In my model, I have this code that controls the database manipulation

```
   public List<contact> displayContact(int? Id)
   {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("displayContact", conn))
        {
            comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@contactId", Id));
            conn.Open();

            List<contact> contactList = new List<contact>();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comObj);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            contactList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                           select new contact()
                           {
                               contactId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["contactId"]),
                               establishmentType = Convert.ToString(dr["establishmentType"]),
                               ownerName = Convert.ToString(dr["ownerName"]),
                               address = Convert.ToString(dr["address"]),
                               city = Convert.ToString(dr["city"]),
                               region = Convert.ToString(dr["region"]),
                               mobileNumber = Convert.ToString(dr["mobileNumber"]),
                               phoneNumber = Convert.ToString(dr["phoneNumber"])
                           }).ToList();

            return contactList;
        }
}
```

My view markup:

```
@model directory.Models.contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>contact</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.contactId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.establishmentType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.establishmentType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.establishmentType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ownerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ownerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ownerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.region, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.region, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.region, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mobileNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mobileNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mobileNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I tried creating a different query to display the edit values, but the exception says my dispayContact stored procedure does not exist even though it does. My other stored procedure works well except for this one.

### Edit

So I fixed my stored procedure in SQL Server; it was named "dispayContact". Still the edit values won't display even after adding `firstOrDefault()` and then changing the declaration in my view from `@model directory.Models.contact` to `@model IEnumerable<directory.Models.contact>`

Comment: You'd change the definition of MVC. Model doesn't suppose to have data operations or manipulation. This should be done in your controller.

Comment: Are you sure your stored proc is called "dispayContact" and not "displayContact" ?

Comment: @kashi_rock it's "displayContact" sorry for the typo error

Comment: Your view is for a single object but you are passing a collection to the view. In your displayContact method change `return contactList;` to `return contactList.FirstOrDefault();` and in your action controller change to `return View(databaseModel.displayContact(id));`

Comment: Isn't OP's problem to do with a stored procedure not being found?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is because you are returning a list

`return View(contact);`

where `contact` is `IEnumerable<contact>` and your view model is

`@model directory.Models.contact`

I guess your code should work once you return the model not list contain the model, in your case return `FirstOrDefault()` of your contact list

something like this

`return View(contact.FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: as I have said in edit, I tried adding `@model IEnumerable<directory.Models.contact>` in my view together with your asnwer. when it didn't work I changed it back to `@model directory.Models.contact` and it now workd. thanks!

Comment: I am glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your function. You can use datareader which is much faster than data adopter. You also don't need to return a collection but just an object of your type:

**Function to get object:**

```
public contact displayContact(int? Id)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("displayContact", conn))
        {
            comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@contactId", Id));
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = comObj.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    return new contact
                    {
                        contactId = int.Parse(dr["contactId"].ToString()),
                        establishmentType = dr["establishmentType"].ToString(),
                        ownerName = dr["ownerName"].ToString(),
                        address = dr["address"].ToString(),
                        city = dr["city"].ToString(),
                        region = dr["region"].ToString(),
                        mobileNumber = dr["mobileNumber"].ToString(),
                        phoneNumber = dr["phoneNumber"].ToString()
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult editContact(int? id)
    {
            var databaseModel = new database();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
           }
        var contact = databaseModel.displayContact(id);
        return View(contact);
    }
```